# Formating content in category.php

Tags: categories, custom-field

I am using WordPress 3.5.1 / Twenty Twelve theme.
I am using custom fields and displaying them in category.php in the following way, the php is setup inside category.php in the "/* Start the Loop */ "

```
$metastime = get_post_meta($post->ID,'user_submit_starttime',true);
echo '<a class="metastime">'.$metastime.'</a>';
$metaetime = get_post_meta($post->ID,'user_submit_endtime',true);
echo '<a class="metaetime">'.$metaetime.'</a>';
$metaloc = get_post_meta($post->ID,'user_submit_location',true);
echo '<a class="metaloc">'.$metaloc.'</a>';
```

It works as the custom fields are displaying when I view the category archives (*the custom fields are displayed under each post title*), but I assume there is a better function to use. Like the the following?

```
get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
```

Since that code is specific to content.php, I would like the custom fields to show up where the

```
<div class="entry-content"> <?php the_content('Read more...'); ?> </div>
```

Resides in content.php, What is the best way to display the custom fields so they display were the "entry-content" is displayed in category.php ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try the `the_content` filter with the conditional tag `is_category()` to append a string to the post content when viewing the category archives :

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'custom_the_content' );
function custom_the_content( $content ){
    if( is_category() ):
        $metastime = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'user_submit_starttime', true );
        $metaetime = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'user_submit_endtime'  , true );
        $metaloc   = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'user_submit_location' , true );
        $content  .= '<a class="metastime">' . $metastime . '</a>';
        $content  .= '<a class="metaetime">' . $metaetime . '</a>';
        $content  .= '<a class="metaloc">'   . $metaloc   . '</a>';
    endif;
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: you can add this into your functions.php file in the current theme directory, or better yet create a plugin from this.

Comment: Adding your code into functions.php did the trick, Thank you.